# Problem with C# in unity. Primary constructor body is not allowed

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is the code. When I try to add the script to the sprite there's the "primary constructor body not allowed" error.
Inside the code editor there are no alerts.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class weapon : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject dapo;
    public float offset;
    public Transform mira;
    private float tiempo;
    public float inicio;
    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ + offset);
        if (tiempo <= 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                Instantiate(dapo, mira.position, transform.rotation);
                tiempo = inicio;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tiempo -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Can you mark which line the compiler is complaining about?  It should give you a line number for that sort of compilation error.

Comment: the problems are in the line 5 and 14

Comment: I don't see anything special/wrong on those lines although you should name your classes starting with capital letters (`Weapon` instead of `weapon`); this is a common convention and helps with readability.  Are you positive you've posted the correct file it's complaining about? That error usually shows up when you've got an errant semi-colon lingering around somewhere but I don't see one in the code you've posted.  And what do you mean when you say "_I try to add the script to the sprite_".  This is a compilation error and you also don't add scripts to sprites, you add them to GameObjects.

Comment: Purely as a guess, does your class name match the file name *exactly?* Including casing (capitals)?